# How many different words can be made using the letters of MISSISSIPPI?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many different words can be made using the letters of $MISSISSIPPI$
>   that start with $M$ or $S$?

I came up with this solution:

- If the word starts with $M$ then:

The numbers of words are $\frac{10!}{4!4!2!}$

- If the word starts with $S$ then:

$\frac{10!}{3!4!2!}$, as I have an $S$ fixed as the first letter.

So the total would be $\frac{10!}{4!4!2!}+\frac{10!}{3!4!2!}$

But the solution I have is $\frac{10!}{4!4!2!}+\frac{4(10!)}{4!4!2!}$, and I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you think that $$\frac{10!}{3!4!2!}$$ and $$\frac{4(10!)}{4!4!2!}$$ are all that different?

Comment: The solutions are equal: $4/4!=1/3!$.

Comment: @did oh! I can't believe I didn't see that.... Lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{4}{4!} = \frac{1}{3!}.
$$